# Supremum of integral polynomial near origin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients that is constant neither in the horizontal nor vertical direction. Prove that $\sup_{-2\leq x,y\leq 2}|P(x,y)|\geq 4$. I suspect we might be able to show a stronger statement that the $\sup$ over pairs of integers in $[-2,2]$ is at least $4$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried applying the extreme value theorem?

Comment: By nonconstant in the two directions, do you mean that there is no $a$ for which $P(a,y)$ is constant, and similarly for $P(x,b)$? Or just that $P(x,y)$ is not a function of $x$ alone, or of $y$ alone? If it's the first one, then my answer below is not a counterexample to your stronger claim, and that claim might be true after all, (and in that case I'll delete my answer)

Comment: pi66-- I have added a counterexample to your stronger claim which works if your intent was as in the first choice of my comment. above.

Comment: pi66 I would still like a reply to clear up what you mean by constant in neither direction, as in the (second comment above.

Comment: It's that $P(x,y)$ is not a function of $x$ alone or of $y$ alone. Both of your counterexamples work for the stronger version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stronger version doesn't hold; take $p(x,y)$ as the product of terms $(x-a)(y-b)$ where $a,b \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$
This $p(x,y)$ is constant in *some* $x$ and $y$ directions. But see below under "added" for another example which is not.

Note: The above polynomial gets quite large at non-integer points.

*Added:* For an example which is not constant in ANY horizontal or vertical direction, let $P(x,y)$ be the product of all terms of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2,$ where again $a,b$ range over all the integer pairs made by two integers each between $-2$ and $2$ inclusive. This will be zero at all the integer pairs, and so is a counterexample to the stronger version, even if it is required that there be no $a$ for which $P(a,y)$ is constant and no $b$ for which $P(x,b)$ is constant.